# Ado.Net Error Procedure or function 'usp_ProjectsCreateNew' expects parameter '@ProjectId', which was not supplied

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures, ado.net

I have parameters like this;

```
    comm.CommandText = "usp_ProjectsCreateNew";

    SqlParameter param = comm.CreateParameter();
    param.ParameterName = "@ProjectId";
    param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    param.DbType = DbType.Int32;
    comm.Parameters.Add(param);

    param = comm.CreateParameter();
    param.ParameterName = "@ProjectHeading";
    param.Value = heading;
    comm.Parameters.Add(param);

    param = comm.CreateParameter();
    param.ParameterName = "@ProjectLongDescription";
    param.Value = longSummary;
    comm.Parameters.Add(param);

    param = comm.CreateParameter();
    param.ParameterName = "@ProjectUrl";
    param.Value = url;
    comm.Parameters.Add(param);

    param = comm.CreateParameter();
    param.ParameterName = "@PromoFront";
    param.Value = promoFront;
    comm.Parameters.Add(param);

    param = comm.CreateParameter();
    param.ParameterName = "@ProjectThumbnail";
    param.Value = thumbnailFileName;
    comm.Parameters.Add(param);

    param = comm.CreateParameter();
    param.ParameterName = "@ProjectImage2";
    param.Value = imageFileName1;
    comm.Parameters.Add(param);

    param = comm.CreateParameter();
    param.ParameterName = "@ProjectImage3";
    param.Value = imageFileName2;
    comm.Parameters.Add(param);

    param = comm.CreateParameter();
    param.ParameterName = "@ProjectImage4";
    param.Value = imageFileName3;
    comm.Parameters.Add(param);

    param = comm.CreateParameter();
    param.ParameterName = "@ProjectImage5";
    param.Value = imageFileName4;
    comm.Parameters.Add(param);

    comm.Transaction = tran;
    int result = comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

My stored procedure code is like this;

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[usp_ProjectsCreateNew]
(
    @ProjectId INT output,
    @ProjectHeading varchar(100),
    @ProjectLongDescription varchar(max),
    @ProjectUrl varchar(100),
    @PromoFront bit,
    @ProjectThumbnail varchar(50),
    @ProjectImage2 varchar(50),
    @ProjectImage3 varchar(50),
    @ProjectImage4 varchar(50),
    @ProjectImage5 varchar(50)
)
AS
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRAN
        INSERT INTO [Projects]([ProjectHeading], [ProjectLongSummary], [ProjectUrl],
            [PromoFront], [ProjectThumbnail], [ProjectImage2], [ProjectImage3], [ProjectImage4], [ProjectImage5])
        VALUES(@ProjectHeading, @ProjectLongDescription, @ProjectUrl, 
            @PromoFront, @ProjectThumbnail, @ProjectImage2, @ProjectImage3, @ProjectImage4, @ProjectImage5);

        SELECT @ProjectId = @@IDENTITY;
    COMMIT TRAN
END Try
BEGIN CATCH
    PRINT Error_Message();
    ROLLBACK TRAN
END CATCH
```

But I am getting this error;

> Message: Procedure or function 'usp_ProjectsCreateNew' expects parameter '@ProjectId', which was not supplied.
>
> Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider
>
> Method: Void OnError(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException, Boolean, System.Action`1[System.Action])

Comment: Very strange, have you tried giving the parameter a value, even though it's an output parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you're not telling the `SqlCommand` that it's a stored procedure!

Add this line:

```
comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

right after setting the `comm`'s `.CommandText` property.

Then: some of your parameters are not clear - I would recommend you use something like this for creating and adding your parameters to the `SqlCommand` object:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@PromoFront", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = 1;
```

I would always explicitly define a `SqlDbType` for each parameter to make it absolutely clear what it is. Not doing so could result in unwanted results.

Comment: Shouldn't he use AddWithValue as recommended by the docs, and set the bit value to true, rather than 1?

Comment: @podiluska: I don't like the `.AddWithValue` since it leaves it up to ADO.NET to guess the type of data you're passing in. That works OK most of the time, but in some cases, it fails. Why not just do it **explicitly** and thus absolutely clear all the time? I prefer that explicit way of doing things. Also: SQL Server `BIT` has values 0 (false) and 1 (true) - so I believe you have to set the parameters to 0 or 1, too

Comment: What a silly mistake. Your answer did help. The prob was comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure. Big thanks to you.